# GOCD - Multiple OS GOCD Agents and pipelines

Tags: go-cd

I am trying to build an application, where some of them should execute on a windows OS and some in linux like Centos/Ubuntu. While designing a pipeline, how can I assure that all the windows related tasks/jobs should go to the windows agent and all the linux related jobs should go to the appropriate linux OS.

What would be ideal approach to achieve this.

Comment: I think the resources option in agent and jobs will do the magic. thanks

Answer (score 4):

[Just to add more information]

You generally enable/add Go agents(which are installed on different operating systems) via the "AGENTS" tab in the Go dashboard. You can tag a Go agent with multiple resources using the "RESOURCES" button in the "AGENTS" tab.

And when you create a job in a stage(in a pipeline), you can mention the resources(which Go agent(s)) to be used to run this job in the "Resources" field of the "Job Settings" tab.

Based on the resources mentioned the Go server will use those Go agents to allocate the jobs. You can tag a Go agent with multiple resources.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have several pipelines that must run on specific machines.  I accomplish this using two methods.

The first is using environments.  I assign specific pipelines to a specific environment (e.g. Developement, QA, Production).  I then assign an agent that has the ability to execute Development related tasks/jobs to the Development environment.  I assign agents that can execute QA related tasks/jobs to the QA environment.

This ensures that pipelines that reside in the Development environment are executed by only agents that are also assigned to the development environment.

If your agent has the ability to execute both Development and QA tasks, then assign the agent to both the Development and QA Environment.

Your can use this same concept to ensure that only windows agents reside in a particular environment.

For example, you can have a Developement-Win environment that you assign pipelines and agents that should handle windows builds.  Another called Development-Linux that you assign agents and pipelines that should handle linux builds.

Since I have agents that can build for multiple environments (Dev, QA and Prop) I also use the "Resources" that are assigned under the "Job Settings" tab.  If the job needs to execute on a windows host, then I will assign a resource of "win2012".  This tells me that the agent must have the resource of "Windows 2012" in order to execute this particular task.

I assign the agent the resource of "win2012" to indicate that it is a windows 2012 resource.

With the combination of the environment configuration and the resource settings the job will only be executed by an agent that meets both the resource requirements and is in the proper environment.

If you have multiple resource requirements for the task you can assign each of them by using a comma separated list.  Some of the resources that I use are msbuild, subversion, sqlcmd.  This tells me that the agent must have access to msbuild (to compile the code), subversion (to acquire it from SVN), and sqlcmd (to execute sql queries against SQL Server).  I then mark agents that contain these particular resources.  Only if an agent meets all of these resource requirements will be assigned the task.